# Making a background image full width when inside a set container

Tags: html, css

I have a container that is set at 1200px. Inside that container i have div that has a background image set via css. I need to make this background image "escape" its full width container that it is trapped in and make it span the entire width of the page. How would i accomplish this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero">
    <p>irrelevant stuff inside</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero {
 background: url("https:example.com") center center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: set the height of the div to 100%. I think the problem is that div doesn't have any height

Comment: I forgot to mention but that container has a height set already.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.hero {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: url('img.jpg');
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Note:** **.container** element should have **'position:static'**. Any other value will not work.